# im trying to an a center image then two images in the side in a php or html file

Tags: html, css

i have a code and i want to add three images a center one a left one and a right one all in the same row how can i do so in my coding i a php what i got so far makes my image go in the center but the other two go under first image

```
<div style="text-align: center;"><IMG SRC="steven.png" ALT="image"></div>
<div style="float: left;"><IMG SRC="star.jpg"></div>
<div style="float: right;"><IMG SRC="star.jpg"></div>



<a href="log.php"> LOGIN </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have each image inside of a div, each div takes up 100% width of the page, so even though your images can be centered the div's (under their default position) will always be placed one under the other.

there are many ways to line them up, here are some that come to mind:

1) style each div with the width you want them then float them accordingly.
2) set the divs width and then their position to relative and use that to fit them to your liking.
3) put them inside LI's inside an UL and use display inline-block.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to show 3 images in a row where first image is aligned left, second is aligned in the middle, and third is aligned right.

```
<div>
    <div style="margin: auto; float: left; width: 33%;">
        <img src="https://cdn.kastatic.org/images/avatars/leaf-red.png" />
    </div>
    <div style="margin: auto; float: left; width: 34%; text-align: center;">
        <img src="https://cdn.kastatic.org/images/avatars/leaf-green.png" />
    </div>
    <div style="margin: auto; float: left; width: 33%;">
        <img style="float: right;" src="https://cdn.kastatic.org/images/avatars/leaf-blue.png" />
    </div>
</div>
```

See [working example](https://jsbin.com/yelacomeze/edit?html,output)

Answer (score 0):

just run with this snippet you can see the boxes aligned properly

```css
.box {
 text-align:center;
 width:100%;
 float:left;
}
.left {
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 display:inline-block;
 text-align:left;
 background:#333;
 float:left;
}
.center {
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 background:#999;
 display:inline-block;
 text-align:center;
}
.right {
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 display:inline-block;
 text-align:right;
 float:right;
 background:#903;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<div class="box">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="center"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
</div><!-- /.box -->

</body>
</html>
```